# Editing the print all button in Magento to ship orders?

Tags: orders, sales-order, backend

My Magento install has a handy "print all" button that lets me print all my PDF  invoices and order confirmations. This is super handy, however would there be a way to extend this so that it ships the order too (and therefore marked as completed)
I don't know where to look. Thanks

Comment: I can sense another tumbleweed...

Comment: I've updated my answer; we added this functionality to our free AutoInvoice extension.

Answer (score 2):

You could start by looking at [our free AutoInvoice](https://github.com/elgentos/AutoInvoice) extension. This gives a nice head start on how to set up an extension to do this, although this creates the invoice, not the shipment.

Then, take a look at Inchoo articles about [programatically shipping an order](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-make-order-shipment-from-code/) and [adding a mass action option to a grid](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-massactions-to-magentos-grid/) in the backend.

With these three combined, you'll be able to create your own extension that does the mass shipping for you.

**UPDATE**: I've extended our AutoInvoice extension since we got a question exactly like this one. Please check it out :)